# Are there Tamil Brahmin followers of Madhvacharya who aren't relatively recent migrants from Karnataka/Andhra Pradesh/Mahrashtra?

Tags: brahmins, madhvacharya, tamil, telugu

On the Wiki page for [Madhva Brahmins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhva_Brahmins), included is a list of Madhva Brahmin communities with a presence in Tamil Nadu, along with notes on where specifically they migrated from. Reproduced here:

> *Dēśastʰa*-s (migrants from Karnataka and Maharashtra), *Aruvattuvākkulu* (migrants from Karnataka), *Baḍaganāḍu*-s (migrants from Karnataka), *Pennāttūrar* Brahmins, *Niyо̄gi* Brahmins (*Aruvela* and
> *Pratʰamaśākʰi*-s).

All these groups are explicitly noted to have an origin outside of Tamil Nadu in fairly recent recorded history, except the *Pennāttūrar* Brahmins. This name seem to be of toponymic origin, suggesting an origin near the banks of the *[Pennā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penna_River)* river in Nellore district of Andhra Pradesh. Note while there does exist a southern *[Peṇṇāṟŭ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponnaiyar_River)* river (i.e., தென்பெண்ணாறு *Teṉpeṇṇāṟŭ*) in Northern Tamil Nadu, I am fairly certain this is not the river being referred to given the non-retroflex *-nn-* sequence in *Pennāttūrar* (the Telugu river name *Pennāru* itself likely was an early borrowing of a Tamil *Peṇṇāṟŭ* “feminine river”, but the loss of retroflexion **-ṇṇ-* ≻ *-nn-* is uniquely Telugu).

Note also the town in Vellore district of Tamil Nadu named *[Pennāttūr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennathur)* (≺ Middle Tamil பென்னாற்றூர் *Pennāṯṯʳūr* “city of the *Pennāṟŭ*” ⬳ Middle Telugu *Pennāṟu* ⬳ Old Tamil *Peṇṇāṟŭ*), which also a lacks retroflex *-ṇṇ-*, suggesting the river name being referred to is a Telugu borrowing of that of the *Pennā* in Andhra Pradesh. Perhaps the *Pennāttūrar* Madhva Brahmins originate from this town, the name memorializing their historic home on the banks of the *Pennā* river in Southern Andhra Pradesh. So, here too, we likely have an example of a Madhva Brahmin community having migrated to Tamil Nadu at some point in the (recent?) past.

Which brings us back to the original question: do (or did) there exist Madhva Tamil Brahmins with historic presence in Tamil Nadu, and what is their history? If not, why did the doctrine of Madhvacharya fail to penetrate into Tamil country and leave a long-lasting following?

Comment: please read forum rules. this is not a historical forum.

Comment: Maybe ask on [History.SE]